# How to pass data through querysting to a web application if it already opened?

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, google-chrome, vb6, salesforce

Suppose I manually launched IE/Chrome browser and have logged into Salesforce. Now if I try to launch/pass data to salesforce through .Net/VB code (invoking Salesforce instance with query string), then salesforce is getting launched in another IE/Chrome browser. So now user has two instances of salesforce open on my machine, which is confusing.

Are there any parameters (for eg. IE/Chrome browser Window name) which we can use to identify if a salesforce window is already open on the machine?

How does Facebook or other Social media works, suppose I've Facebook instance open & I shared a artical, but it doesn't open another window but use the existing open window.

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The app's are living in different worlds. Unless Saleforce have plug-ins for IE or Chrome or Firefox that specifically communicate with client side software, then there is no way to do it directly, you may be able to hack some of it using FindWindow API's etc., but you've no reliable way to do this at all. :-(